# Free throw shooting (& combining binomial distributions?)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let's stay that Steph makes 90% of his free throws while LeBron makes 70%. If they each shoot 100 free throws, what is the probability that Steph makes more free throws than LeBron?

I think it's fair to assume that the number of free throws Steph makes is a binomial random variable $X \sim Binomial(100, 0.9)$. Similarly, the number LeBron makes is $Y \sim Binomial(100, 0.7)$. So, I am trying to find out $P(X > Y)$. If it helps, we could define the difference as $D = X - Y$ and then I am trying to find $P(D  > 0)$. This is where I get stuck - how do I combine two binomial distributions to figure out how $D$ is distributed?

Also, would the question be more difficult (or different) to answer if the two players shot different numbers of free throws?

Comment: While you can write down the answer in terms of binomial distributions, it will be ugly.  I think you're probably supposed use the normal approximation to the number of free throws made, and use the fact that the difference between two normal distributions is normal.

Comment: Thanks for the help - although this is not for any course, just something I woke up thinking about. I will try the normal approximation - I realize that works since I picked an arbitrary n that is large enough. But what if LeBron and Steph were only shooting 10 free throws each?

Comment: If they were only shooting $10$ free throws apiece, I would just use the binomial distribution.  I got the same answer as @MathLover, though I just wrote down the formula; I didn't plug it into WolframAlpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, $X$ is the random variable for Steph's making his free throws and $Y$ for LeBron.

If you are looking for the exact form, it will look as below -

$\displaystyle P(X \gt Y) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} {n \choose k}  \, (0.9)^k \, (0.1)^{(n-k)} \, \sum \limits_{i=0}^{k-1} {n \choose i}  (0.7)^i  \, (0.3)^{(n-i)}$

For $X = k$ successes, we know that $0 \leq Y \leq k-1 \,$ are acceptable.

Distribution for just $n = 2$ is

$P(X \gt Y) =  0.4293, P(X \lt Y) = 0.0973, P(X = Y) = 0.4734$.

Checking WolframAlpha for $n = 10$ throws, I get $P(X \gt Y)$ as $\approx 0.81$ which was $0.4923$ for $n = 2$.